# Interpretation of IMU-Data (ROS & XSens MTi)

Tags: c++, ros

We have an XSens MTi and subscribe to the IMU Data via sensor_msgs::IMU.

The output of linear_acceleration is:

x: 0.12
y: 0.02
z: 9.83

all changing in a small range. What does this data tell me? Why is the robot apparently accelerating in z-direction. The robot stands still.

Orientation Data is good, but the linear acceleration confuse me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The acceleration in z-direction is caused by the [gravity of the earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth) which is about 9.81 N/kg (or equivalently m/s²) with some small variation depending on the actual location on earth.
If an object is standing still, it is always accelerated by this amount towards the ground (this is why things fall down, if there is nothing to hold them). So if you want to know the acceleration of the robot relative to its surroundings you have to subtract this value.

Some implications of this:

1. If your z-acceleration is zero, this means the robot is in free fall. For your robot it is probably too late then, but for some applications it can be useful to detect this and activate some safety functions to prevent damage.
2. You can use this fact to calculate the orientation of the sensor. For example if you suddenly have y = 9.81 and z = 0, this means your robot has fallen to the side. In your case, the small non-zero values of x and y could indicate that the sensor is not oriented absolutely horizontal.